# Render the Flash message through js.erb file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, flash, render

In my Rails app, I want to render the flash message from my controller method `delete_option` (`questions_controller`) to a partial `_edit.html.erb` inside questions folder itself. I have a js file `delete_option.js.erb` and I could successfully render the edit using the below line to a div element with id `edit_subquestion`.

```
$("#edit_subquestion").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "edit")) %>");
```

I put a div element inside the `_edit.html.erb` to render the flash message as given below.

```
<div id="flash_delete_option"></div>
```

I am trying to render the flash message from the method `delete_option` to the above `div` element as given below.

```
if((<%=flash[:success]%>).length > 0)
    $("#flash_delete_option").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('<%=flash[:success]%>')) %>");
```

I am getting syntax errors. Please help to resolve this. Everything tried as per the answer. Not getting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ruby to do conditionals in your edit.js.erb file. Also, since you're inside the escape_javascript, you don't call render in there.

```
<% if flash[:success] %>
    $("#flash_delete_option").html("<%= escape_javascript flash[:success]%>");
<% end %>
```

Comment: There's no syntax error here. It must be elsewhere (please post the syntax error)

Comment: SyntaxError in Questions#delete_option

Showing /home/local/Rajesh/VX/app/views/questions/delete_option.js.erb where line #2 raised:

compile error
/home/local/Rajesh/VX/app/views/questions/delete_option.js.erb:2: syntax error, unexpected ';'
...lash_delete_option").html("');@output_buffer.append= ( escap...
                              ^

Extracted source (around line #2):

1: <% if flash[:success]? %>
2:     $("#flash_delete_option").html("<%= escape_javascript flash[:success]%>");
3: <% end %>
4: 
5: <% if flash[:notice]? %>

Comment: Please update with your current app/views/questions/delete_option.js.erb  --- it does not match mine.

Comment: Sorry, I need to put it over here?

Comment: You can update your question if you'd like. Or paste a link to a gist

Answer (score 0):

Jesse Wolgamott : if loop was the problem. I modified it. now, its working.

```
<% unless flash[:success].blank? %>
    $("div .success").html("<%= escape_javascript (raw(flash[:success])) %>");
    $("div .success").show(200);
    $("div .success").click(function(){
        $("div .success").hide(200);
    });
<% end %>
```