# How to return flash to page from remote controller rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am using `remote:true` as the option in a rails form. I happily posts to a remote controller. I was wondering if it is possible to return a flash (something like `flash.now[:success]`) to the pager with the form on. 
Many thanks

Comment: Yes, this is possible.

Comment: Of course you can, you just need to render that flash partial page in you `action_name.js.erb` . and i dn't know how are you using this to show flash message.

Comment: @Tom do you any partial for flash messages?

Comment: I'm using bootstrap and there is a partial at the top of the page where they usually show.

Comment: is that partial contains flash message code?

Comment: Yes, it contains `<% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>`

Comment: try something like this https://coderwall.com/p/ww6dpg/display-ajax-flash-message-with-rails-js OR https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024835/render-the-flash-message-through-js-erb-file

Comment: so in your header div just render this partial.

Answer (score 0):

in your controller's action

```
 def my_action
   //.....
  flash[:success] = "data saved successfully!"
 end
```

in your `my_action.js.erb` file

```
<%if flash[:success].present?%>
  $('#header_id').html("<%= j render 'your_flash_message_partial'%>");
<%end%>
```

`header_id` is id of div where you commonly display your your flash message.

`your_flash_message_partial` is complete path of your partial of flash message page

Comment: you mean `flash.now[:success]` ?

Comment: dn't use `flash.now[:success]` untill it doesn't need. `flash.now` is to be used where you need to display on same page before redirect to another page. hmm i can't explain but there is difference between flash and flash.now.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh [`ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash#now`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash/FlashHash.html#method-i-now) is far more temporary.

Comment: I am aware of the difference. I am just assuming user if not redirecting instead rendering a js template. So, `flash.now` might work.